# Snowflake - Many tasks dependencies for a task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to know whether there is a way to run a task after a series of tasks are finished. Snowflake as far I understand, only supports just 1 predecessor task, not many.

My case is that I have to load a Fact table after all Dimensions are finished.

Comment: HI one way could be write one task which will call all one procedure and that procedure will call all the the other procedures one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to define multiple predecessors for a task.

[Tasks: DAG Support — Preview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-06.html#tasks-dag-support-preview)

> [image]
>
> source: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/_images/data-pipeline-tasks-dag-example-basic.png
>
> The root task (A) runs on a schedule, such as “every 5 minutes” or “every day at 5 AM and 5 PM.” Tasks B and C run simultaneously when Task A runs to completion. Task D runs only when both Tasks B and C complete their runs.
>
> **DAGs enable parallel processing workflows that were impossible or difficult to achieve using task trees**, including:
>
> - Updating a set of dimension tables concurrently before aggregating facts for a dashboard.
> - Prompting a notification through a remote messaging service using an external function after all previous tasks have run to completion.

---

Sample scenario:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
CREATE SCHEMA TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task SCHEDULE = '10 minute' AS SELECT system$wait(20);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task2 AFTER task1 AS SELECT system$wait(20);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task3 AFTER task1 AS SELECT system$wait(20);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task4 AFTER task3 AS SELECT system$wait(50);

-- adding second predecessor, with ALTER statement
ALTER TASK task4 ADD AFTER task2;
```

Checking metadata:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_DEPENDENTS(
           TASK_NAME => 'task1', RECURSIVE => TRUE )) t;
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Diagram was generated using script from: [Snowflake Tasks - Visualizing hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67558334/5070879)

EDIT:

It is possible to define multiple predecessor tasks at CREATE TASK level:

[Tasks: Support for Specifying Multiple Predecessor Tasks in a Single SQL Statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-08.html#tasks-support-for-specifying-multiple-predecessor-tasks-in-a-single-sql-statement)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task4 AFTER task2, task3 AS SELECT system$wait(50);
```