# How to call procedures in Snowflake with an order

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that have columns `PROCEDURE_NAME, PROCEDURE_LAYER, PROCEDURE_DATABASE, ORDER`
Here are the values

```
'PROCEDURE_1,BUSINESS,PROD,1'
'PROCEDURE_2,BUSINESS,PROD,2'
'PROCEDURE_3,BUSINESS,PROD,3'
```

How to call this procedures in order from 1 to 3?. I can add that the second procedure should start loading after the first one is finished. The fird one should start loading after the second one is finished etc.

Comment: An alternative approach is defining the operations as series of interconnected tasks that forms  DAG. Related: [Snowflake - Many tasks dependencies for a task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72621470/5070879)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine [execute immediate](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html#) with a [loop](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/for.html#) over that table.

```sql
execute immediate $$
declare 
    c1 cursor for select PROCEDURE_NAME
                  from   procedure_table
                  order by ORDER;
begin
    open c1;
    for rec in c1 do
        execute immediate 'call '||rec.PROCEDURE_NAME||'()'
    end for;
    return 'Completed';
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Can I add this cursor to the  Snowflake procedure?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [same constructs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors.html) in a stored procedure.